# form the largest number possible in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

Given a list such as:
[3, 30, 34, 5, 9].
Output: 9534330
Write a program to return the largest number possible

In my code I have used permutation here:

```
from itertools import permutations
x = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
y = permutations(x)
n = len(y)
e = []
for i in y:
    a = map(str, i)
    e.append(int("".join(i)))
print "Largest Number {}".format(sorted(e)[-1])
```

Here n which is the length of the number of permutations is 120 because of 5!.
Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting all numbers in descending order is the simplest solution that occurs to us. But this doesn’t work.

For example, 548 is greater than 60, but in the output, 60 comes before 548. As a second example, 98 is greater than 9, but 9 comes before 98 in the output.

The solution is to use any comparison based sorting algorithm. Thus, instead of using the default comparison, write a comparison function myCompare() and use it to sort numbers.

Given two numbers X and Y, how should myCompare() decide which number to put first – we compare two numbers XY (Y appended at the end of X) and YX (X appended at the end of Y).

If XY is larger, then, in the output, X should come before Y, else Y should come before X.

For example, let X and Y be 542 and 60. To compare X and Y, we compare 54260 and 60542. Since 60542 is greater than 54260, we put Y first.

Calculating Permutations yield a higher time complexity.
A better solution in python would be:

```
def largestNumber(A):
    maxlen = len(str(max(A)))
    if all(v == 0 for v in A):
        return '0'
    return ''.join(sorted((str(v) for v in A), reverse=True,
                      key=lambda i: i*(maxlen * 2 // len(i))))

largestNumber([3, 30, 34, 5, 9])
```

Comment: Explanation welcome.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Added an explanation. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: That's much clearer now. But is the relation "comes before" transitive ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes the relation "comes before" can be said to be transitive.
i.e. if 60 > 542, and 542 > 4323, then 60 > 4323

Comment: Mh, a single "obvious" example is not a proof.

Comment: The key function is unclear to me.  Why do you need to perform that repeating of the string for the lex-sorting? Why can't you just lex-sort descending the  *strings* of the numbers themselves, without that `maxlen` repetition?  The key function also bears no resemblance to the explanation, as comparing XY to YX as you claim isn't what the key function is doing.  Further clarification would be helpful.

Comment: Do you really mean `maxlen = len(str(max(A)))` (number of digits of the greatest value) or `max(len(str(a)) for a in A)` (max number of digits of one value)

Comment: I don't think your lambda always gives strings of the same size. I would do : `lambda i: (i*maxlen)[:maxlen]` Am I correct ?

Comment: I think you can replace `if all(v == 0 for v in A)` with `if not all(A)`.

Comment: I have now found an easy way to prove transitivity. See my renewed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem leads to an interesting transformation that is worth explaining.

Assume we want to know which of `XY` or `YX` is larger for given `X` and `Y`. Numerically, we want the largest of `X.10^y + Y` and `Y.10^x + X`, where the lowercase denote the number of digits of the uppercase variables.

Then with a little math, the comparison

```
X.10^y + Y < Y.10^x + X
```

can be rewritten

```
X / (10^x - 1) < Y / (10^y - 1)
```

so that `XY < YX` is certainly a transitive relation and defines a total order. This is very good news because it means that the problem can be reduced to ordinary sorting by using this modified comparison operation.

Now notice that `X / (10^x - 1)` is a periodic fractional number of the form `0.XXXX...`, and to compare `0.XXXX...` and `0.YYYY...`, it suffices to compare over the longest period. Hence the comparison can work as an ordinary string comparison, except that when the end of the shorter string is reached, we cycle back to the first character.

E.g. `12345 > 12` because `12345 > 12|12|1` and `12105 < 12` because `12105 < 12|12|1`.

The comparison function can be described as follows:

```
def Cmp(X, Y):
    l= max(len(X), len(Y))
    for i in range(l):
        if X[i % len(X)] < Y[i % len(Y)]:
            return 1 # X > Y
        elif X[i % len(X)] > Y[i % len(Y)]:
            return -1 # X < Y
    return 0 # X == Y
```

I don't recommend this particular implementation, which will be slow because of the `%`.

Comment: Remember python2 will be dead in 2 years. Please avoid giving python2-only answers.
In python3 the syntax is: `from functools import cmp_to_key

print(sorted(['3', '30', '34', '5', '9'], key=cmp_to_key(Precedes)))`

Comment: Does someone know how to add line breaks in comments ?

Comment: But your answer is useful and will be available to all readers after 2020. We must forget of python2 now (except those who must maintain legacy code)

Comment: I completely rewrote this answer, the above comments are no more relevant.